# Timestamp returned as weird string

Tags: php, pdo, cassandra

When I select a `timestamp` from the cassandra database via PDO ([YACassandraPDO](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO) is also installed), I get the following output;

```
Bý£1€
```

Identified as a `string(8)` in a `var_dump`

This value should be `December 17th 2013 00:00:00`

As a guess, I tried `$arr = unpack("l", $raw['date']);` which results in

```
Array([1] => 1107361792)
```

But converting from epoch, this equals: `2005-2-02`

Can anyone tell me what I'm supposed to do?

**UPDATE**

By the way, the timestamps show up just fine in the CQL commandline and DevCenter.

**UPDATE 2**

Here's the method I use to select the rows;

```
function getAny($limit=100)
{
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM \"".$this->tableName."\" LIMIT $limit;");
    if($stmt->execute() === false)
    {
        $this->logError($stmt, "getAny");
        return false;
    }
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but it seems to be as good a solution as it's going to get; I simple changed the column types to `bigint` to store the epoch time & it's working fine now. If anyone ever finds out what was going on, I'd love to know!

Answer (score 0):

Check that the timestamp is correct at the time of insertion into the database. The epoch time string you should have is 1387238400

Comment: I probably should have said the timestamp shows up just fine when selecting from the cassandra CQL commandline. So it's something on PHP's end.